# Power BI: Add a column that is a level ahead of the related column

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, data-analysis, powerbi-desktop

I have two columns:

| User | Parent |
| --- | --- |
| Amy K. | Theo K. |
| Lena K. | Theo K. |
| Jiha L. | John L. |
| John L. | Victor L. |
| Theo K. | Simba K. |
| Simba K. | Ellen K. |

Now I need to make another column called Grandparent where I need to put users from the User column in the Grandparent column if they are Parents of the people in the Parent column. So it would look like this:

| User | Parent | Grandparent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Amy K. | Theo K. | Simba K. |
| Lena K. | Theo K. | Simba K. |
| Jiha L. | John L. | Victor L. |
| John L. | Victor L. | null |
| Theo K. | Simba K. | Ellen K. |
| Simba K. | Ellen K. | null |

I tried to do so by adding a column and doing a coupling with a DAX measure, but nothing seemed to work.

Comment: I have rolled back as the original question posed has been answered. Please mark this as solved and ask a new question if your requirements have changed.

Answer (score 3):

In Power BI you can use the `LOOKUPVALUE` (DAX) function:

```
Grandparent = LOOKUPVALUE('Table'[Parent],'Table'[User],[Parent])
```

[image]

In Power Query (M), you could add a custom column:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WcsytVPDWU9JRCslIzQexYnWilXxS8xIxRb0yMxIVfECiXvkZeSAWWBTK1lEKy0wuyS+CicN06igFZ+YmJcIMgXN0lFxzclLzwOKxAA==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [User = _t, Parent = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"User", type text}, {"Parent", type text}}),
    
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Grandparent", each 
        try Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", (r)=>r[User]=[Parent])[Parent]{0} 
            otherwise null, type text)
in
    #"Added Custom"
```

[image]

Comment: I am so sorry, I asked a wrong question. It should actually not be done by Power BI but with PostgreSQL.

Comment: I actually need to somehow select parent column in database but show it in Power BI as grandparent column.

Comment: You should mark this as solved and then ask a new question as Ron has gone out of his way to help. Upvoted

Comment: I wanted to do so, however I can not ask a new question for 90 mins I think. And this may be useful too because people with a similar problem will see the solution on the same problem from two points of view: Power BI and SQL.

Comment: OK. The point still stands that this particular question should be marked as solved.

Comment: Grandparent = LOOKUPVALUE('Table'[Parent],'Table'[User],[Parent])  I tried this but it gives me error with the [Parent] argument. Second solution is not compatible either.

Comment: I have tested both and they work.

Comment: @Ravena I suspect there is some difference between the data that you are applying this to and the data that you presented in your question. But from your comment I cannot tell where the problem lies. Perhaps if you supply a more realistic data sample? Obviously, it works here with the data you presented or I would not have been able to produce the results screenshots. For example, if you have identical names in the first column, errors can be produced. But you did not show any instances of that nor what should happen if that were the case.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld When using Grandparent = LOOKUPVALUE('Table'[Parent],'Table'[User],[Parent]), did you do it by adding a new column in POWER BI? I tried to do it that way and got a syntax error that [Parent] (third argument) can not be found or used. The second one is using json as a table so its not what I am looking for.